# How to speed up unit tests with less configuration

Tags: spring-boot, jhipster

The unit test template of jhipster is great, but sometime, especially, during coding, I need to write unit test code and run frequently. But now the unit test will start tomcat container and many other module, which I don't need if I want to test a service function.

Now the test class is like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = Application.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@IntegrationTest
@Transactional
public class SomeClassTest {
    .....
```

How can I modify it to only initialize spring container and DB? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not need the server, don't make your test an integration test. If you remove `@WebAppConfiguration` and `@IntegrationTest` spring boot will start a regular (i.e. non-web context) and will not start Tomcat.

If you need to go even further, you can disable certain features, either via `application-test.properties` + `@ActiveProfiles("test")` to disable stuff via config or using the `exclude` parameter of `@SpringBootApplication` (or `@EnableAutoConfiguration`) as Lukas said already.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this question [How to exclude *AutoConfiguration classes in Spring Boot JUnit tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26698071/how-to-exclude-autoconfiguration-classes-in-spring-boot-junit-tests) and see if this helps you. The idea is to explicitly exclude auto configurations that you don't need in your test, so in your case it would probably be `EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration`