# Disabling RedisHttpSessionConfiguration in junit tests

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-profiles

I'm using `spring-boot` and `spring-session` to build a simple rest api. The production application should use the redis-session implementation, whereas the tests should use the default (non-redis) spring-session.

However when the `spring-boot-starter-redis` maven dependency is declared in the project, spring-boot will automagically create a `org.springframework.session.data.redis.config.annotation.web.http.RedisHttpSessionConfiguration` without the `@EnableRedisHttpSession` annotation being anywhere in the test configuration.

My setup

Application code:

```java
// base session config for both prod/dev and test/ci
public class BaseSessionConfig {

  @Bean
  public HeaderHttpSessionStrategy sessionStrategy() {
    return new HeaderHttpSessionStrategy();
  }

}

// enable the redis session only in these profiles
@Configuration
@EnableRedisHttpSession
@Profile({"prod", "dev", "local", "vagrant"})
public class RedisSessionConfig extends BaseSessionConfig {


}
```

Tests:

```java
@WebIntegrationTest
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = {MyApplication.class, MyTestApplicationConfig.class})
public class AuthenticationResourceTest {

  private RestTemplate restTemplate = new TestRestTemplate();

  @Test
  public void testUnauthenticated() {

    HttpHeaders headers = restTemplate.getForEntity("http://localhost:8080/api/session", String.class).getHeaders();

    // ...    
  }

}

// session configuration for the test environments
// no redis enabled    
@Configuration
@Profile({"ci", "test"})
public class MyTestApplicationConfig extends BaseSessionConfig {


}
```

How can i disable the redis session auto-configuration inside the junit tests?

The stack trace during tests:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:228)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:230)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:249)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:89)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:119)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:42)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:234)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:74)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'enableRedisKeyspaceNotificationsInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/session/data/redis/config/annotation/web/http/RedisHttpSessionConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.redis.RedisConnectionFailureException: Cannot get Jedis connection; nested exception is redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Could not get a resource from the pool
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:764)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.doRun(SpringApplication.java:357)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:305)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.SpringApplicationContextLoader.loadContext(SpringApplicationContextLoader.java:98)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: org.springframework.data.redis.RedisConnectionFailureException: Cannot get Jedis connection; nested exception is redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Could not get a resource from the pool
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory.fetchJedisConnector(JedisConnectionFactory.java:162)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory.getConnection(JedisConnectionFactory.java:251)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory.getConnection(JedisConnectionFactory.java:58)
    at org.springframework.session.data.redis.config.annotation.web.http.RedisHttpSessionConfiguration$EnableRedisKeyspaceNotificationsInitializer.afterPropertiesSet(RedisHttpSessionConfiguration.java:166)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
    ... 40 more
Caused by: redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Could not get a resource from the pool
    at redis.clients.util.Pool.getResource(Pool.java:50)
    at redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool.getResource(JedisPool.java:99)
    at redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool.getResource(JedisPool.java:12)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory.fetchJedisConnector(JedisConnectionFactory.java:155)
    ... 45 more
Caused by: redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.connect(Connection.java:164)
    at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryClient.connect(BinaryClient.java:82)
    at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryJedis.connect(BinaryJedis.java:1641)
    at redis.clients.jedis.JedisFactory.makeObject(JedisFactory.java:85)
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.create(GenericObjectPool.java:868)
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:435)
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:363)
    at redis.clients.util.Pool.getResource(Pool.java:48)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.connect(Connection.java:158)
    ... 55 more
```

### Edit

I figured it out. The reason why the `RedisHttpSessionConfig` is loaded in tests despite not having the `EnableRedisSession` annotation on the config is this auto-configuration which comes with spring-boot-starter-web: [SessionAutoConfiguration](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/9681df0e9f8790b0d30f032a6460a957289ea05b/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/session/SessionAutoConfiguration.java#L51)

So in tests, this is the class which needs to be excluded from autoconfiguration:

```
@WebIntegrationTest
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = TestAppConfig.class)
public class AuthenticationResourceTest {

  private RestTemplate restTemplate = new TestRestTemplate();

  @Test
  public void testUnauthenticated() {

    HttpHeaders headers = restTemplate.getForEntity("http://localhost:8080/api/session", String.class).getHeaders();

  }

}


@Configuration
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {SessionAutoConfiguration.class, SessionRedisHttpConfiguration.class})
public class TestAppConfig {

  @Configuration
  static class SessionConfig extends BaseSessionConfig {

  }

}
```

Comment: try annotating MyTestApplicationConfig with @SpringBootApplication and do this @SpringBootApplication(exclude = RedisHttpSessionConfiguration.class)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`@ActiveProfiles`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#integration-testing-annotations-spring) testing annotation to enable certain profiles for test. If you don't activate profiles defined on `RedisSessionConfig` that configuration shouldn't be loaded.

But also make sure that `RedisHttpSessionConfiguration` is not loaded by auto-configuration.

**Reaction on Comment:**

I wasn't sure if Redis has it's auto-configuration class. [Looking into Spring Boot](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v1.3.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/redis/RedisAutoConfiguration.java), it has. So you need to exclude it during test. [Look into this SO thread how to do it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26698071/how-to-exclude-autoconfiguration-classes-in-spring-boot-junit-tests).

Comment: Unfortunately that does not work. I've tried a similar suggestion like it's mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26698071/how-to-exclude-autoconfiguration-classes-in-spring-boot-junit-tests - but `RedisHttpSessionConfiguration` is still loaded in the test (also with `@ActiveProfiles({"test"})` enabled.

As far as i understand spring-boot autoconfig, there needs to be a `META-INF/spring.factories` file containing the auto-configuration classes + some `@Conditional` annotations on the config. however, this config has none of that: https://git.io/vzO1C