# Why does InboundChannelAdapter not work in SpringBootTest

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

In a spring-boot project i am using the following code:

```
import org.springframework.integration.core.MessageSource;

@Configuration
public class Config
{

@Bean
@InboundChannelAdapter(channel = "channel1", autoStartup = "false",
      poller = @Poller("poller"))
public MessageSource messages() throws Exception
{
...
```

to poll a mailaccount for incoming messages. This works fine so far.

The problem arises when i try to call some tests in a class that is annotated with `@SpringBootTest`. Then the initialisation of my testclass fails:

```
2023-01-12T16:43:03.846+01:00 ERROR 3625 --- [           main] o.s.test.context.TestContextManager      : Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@63648ee9] to prepare test instance [MyClass@b849fa6]

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:131) ~[spring-test-6.0.0-M5.jar:6.0.0-M5]
    <... stacktrace ...>
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The 'interface org.springframework.integration.annotation.InboundChannelAdapter' on @Bean method level is allowed only for: org.springframework.integration.core.MessageSource, or java.util.function.Supplier, or kotlin.jvm.functions.Function0 beans
    <... more stacktrace...>
```

I can't see the problem here, since the annotation is used together with MessageSource. Can someone help me on this one, please?

update in reply to the comment from Vitaly Chura:
in fact, that does not tell me much, unfortunately, but i will give it a try:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The 'interface org.springframework.integration.annotation.InboundChannelAdapter' on @Bean method level is allowed only for: org.springframework.integration.core.MessageSource, or java.util.function.Supplier, or kotlin.jvm.functions.Function0 beans
at org.springframework.util.Assert.isTrue(Assert.java:139) ~[spring-core-6.0.0-M5.jar:6.0.0-M5]
at org.springframework.integration.config.annotation.InboundChannelAdapterAnnotationPostProcessor.createMessageSource(InboundChannelAdapterAnnotationPostProcessor.java:100) ~[spring-integration-core-6.0.0-M4.jar:6.0.0-M4]
at org.springframework.integration.config.annotation.InboundChannelAdapterAnnotationPostProcessor.postProcess(InboundChannelAdapterAnnotationPostProcessor.java:72) ~[spring-integration-core-6.0.0-M4.jar:6.0.0-M4]
at org.springframework.integration.config.annotation.MessagingAnnotationPostProcessor.postProcessMethodAndRegisterEndpointIfAny(MessagingAnnotationPostProcessor.java:231) ~[spring-integration-core-6.0.0-M4.jar:6.0.0-M4]
at org.springframework.integration.config.annotation.MessagingAnnotationPostProcessor.lambda$processAnnotationTypeOnMethod$4(MessagingAnnotationPostProcessor.java:220) ~[spring-integration-core-6.0.0-M4.jar:6.0.0-M4]
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.integration.config.annotation.MessagingAnnotationPostProcessor.afterSingletonsInstantiated(MessagingAnnotationPostProcessor.java:135) ~[spring-integration-core-6.0.0-M4.jar:6.0.0-M4]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:941) ~[spring-beans-6.0.0-M5.jar:6.0.0-M5]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:926) ~[spring-context-6.0.0-M5.jar:6.0.0-M5]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:592) ~[spring-context-6.0.0-M5.jar:6.0.0-M5]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:731) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0-M4.jar:3.0.0-M4]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:430) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0-M4.jar:3.0.0-M4]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0-M4.jar:3.0.0-M4]
at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:132) ~[spring-boot-test-3.0.0-M4.jar:3.0.0-M4]
at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98) ~[spring-test-6.0.0-M5.jar:6.0.0-M5]
at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:123) ~[spring-test-6.0.0-M5.jar:6.0.0-M5]
... 72 common frames omitted
```

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The 'interface org.springframework.integration.annotation.InboundChannelAdapter' on @Bean method level is allowed only for: org.springframework.integration.core.MessageSource, or java.util.function.Supplier, or kotlin.jvm.functions.Function0 beans
    <... more stacktrace...>` what if you try debugging from the latest line in that piece of stacktrace? Maybe you could find out why it throws an IllegalArgumentException and what is wrong there.

Answer (score 0):

I know this does not explain the IllegalArgumentException, but for reasons of pragmatism  i circumvented this problem by implementing a dummy configuration class inside the test-folder of the maven-project that provides the same beans as the original but does not use the @InboundChannelAdapter, as suggested by Matheus Santz in [how-to-exclude-java-configuration-class-from-test-context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39729752/java-spring-boot-test-how-to-exclude-java-configuration-class-from-test-context). So for the tests this new dummy class is used.
Thanx to Vitaly Chura and all others reading.