# Spring ComponentScan excludeFilters annotation not working in Spring Boot Test context

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-annotations, spring-test

I am using Spring Boot 1.4.3.RELEASE and want to exclude some components from being scanned when running the tests.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@ComponentScan(
        basePackages = {"com.foobar"},
        excludeFilters =  @Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, classes = {AmazonKinesisRecordChecker.class, MyAmazonCredentials.class}))
public class ApplicationTests {

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {
    }

}
```

Despite the filters, when I run the test the unwanted components are loaded and Spring Boot crashes as those classes require an AWS environment to work properly:

```
2017-01-25 16:02:49.234 ERROR 10514 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'amazonKinesisRecordChecker' defined in file
```

**Question:** how can I make the filters working?

Comment: @SpringBootTest(classes=<<choose classes to load >> ) . Docs : http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/context/SpringBootTest.html

Comment: @Barath Are you saying there is only a way to include classes, but not to exclude them when in Spring Boot Test?

Comment: No I am not saying so, you can use WebMvcTest  to exclude filters Doc :http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcTest.html

Comment: for your information : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26698071/how-to-exclude-autoconfiguration-classes-in-spring-boot-junit-tests

Comment: `@ComponentScan` on a test class is not working nor useful. It will only work on `@Configuration` classes. Next to that even if it would be accepted it wouldn't work. As there would be an additional `@ComponentScan` on your application class one would detect the component and the other wouldn't. With the same result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you need is, not to exclude them but to mock them instead, using `@MockBean`. As shown below

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class ApplicationTests {
    @MockBean
    AmazonCredentials amazonCredentials;

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {
    }
}
```

This way you will let Spring Context know that you want to mock the `AmazonCredentials` bean. Sometimes, excluding filters is a bit tricky to work with.

Hope this helps! I would love to explore if we have another way to get this done.