# class required a single bean, but 2 were found:

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have the below interface:

```
public interface MailSender {
    void sender(String to, String subject,String body);
}
```

With 2 imlementation of it:

```
public class SmtpkMailSender implements MailSender   {

    static Log log=LogFactory.getLog(MailSender.class); 

    public void sender(String to, String subject,String body){
        log.info("SMTP To: "+to);
        log.info("SMTP Subjecy: "+subject);
        log.info("SMTP body: "+body);
    }

}
```

and the second one is:

```
@Primary
public class MockMailSender implements MailSender   {

    static Log log=LogFactory.getLog(MailSender.class); 

    public void sender(String to, String subject,String body){
        log.info("To: "+to);
        log.info("Subject: "+subject);
        log.info("body: "+body);
    }

}
```

I used the dependency injection into the controller class which is as following:

```
@RestController
public class MailController {

    @Autowired
    private MailSender smtpkMailSender;

    @RequestMapping("/send")
    public String send(){
        smtpkMailSender.sender("Person", "Important", "Take Care");
        return "mail is sent";
    }
}
```

At the end i have a configuration class which contains my Beans:

```
@Configuration
public class MailConfig {

    @Bean
    public SmtpkMailSender getSmtpkMailSender(){
        return new SmtpkMailSender();
    }

    @Bean
    public MockMailSender getMockMailSender(){
        return new MockMailSender();
    }

}
```

Unfortunatly, when i run my application it complains with:

```
Description:

Field smtpkMailSender in com.example.demo.MailController required a single bean, but 2 were found:
    - getSmtpkMailSender: defined by method 'getSmtpkMailSender' in class path resource [com/example/mail/MailConfig.class]
    - getMockMailSender: defined by method 'getMockMailSender' in class path resource [com/example/mail/MailConfig.class]


Action:

Consider marking one of the beans as @Primary, updating the consumer to accept multiple beans, or using @Qualifier to identify the bean that should be consumed
```

As you see, although i have specified the `MockMailSender` as Primary the spring still complains, and cannot identify it

Comment: Add a qualifier to spell out which bean you intend to inject.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Since you're using java config you should mark config method with `@Primary` annotation, and not a class:

```
@Configuration
public class MailConfig {
    @Bean
    public SmtpkMailSender getSmtpkMailSender(){
        return new SmtpkMailSender();
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public MockMailSender getMockMailSender(){
        return new MockMailSender();
    }
}
```

Comment: How can i call service of my choice based on some condition?

Comment: @AakashPatel, you can inject all of them using Qualifier annotation with a name of the bean as value. Then use any of them based on your condition

Answer (score 20):

You can use @Qualifier annotation for specify which specific type of your implementation, you want to autowire.

```
@RestController
public class MailController {

   @Autowired
   @Qualifier("smtpkMailSender")
   private MailSender smtpkMailSender;

   @RequestMapping("/send")
   public String send(){
      smtpkMailSender.sender("Person", "Important", "Take Care");
      return "mail is sent";
  }
```

}

Comment: is it possible to make the qualifier value configurable?

Comment: it is possible, follow below link  
                       https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7812745/spring-qualifier-and-property-placeholder

Answer (score 3):

Another solution for this error is to `exclude` the Bean that is not used (*the duplicated bean*), from the `autoconfiguration` stage within "***application.yml***" file, as explained in this thread: [How to exclude AutoConfiguration classes in Spring Boot JUnit tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26698071/how-to-exclude-autoconfiguration-classes-in-spring-boot-junit-tests)

```yaml
spring:
  autoconfigure:
    exclude:
      - org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration 
      - org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.integration.IntegrationAutoConfiguration
```

---

This is applicable if the error appears after you added a new Maven/Gradle dependency, which duplicates an existing bean that you are using. For example, when both beans come from external JARs, so the source code cannot be updated with `@Primary` or `@Qualifier` annotations to solve the error.

Answer (score 2):

You may simply name your bean using

```
@Bean(name="mockMailSender")
public MockMailSender getMockMailSender() { }
```

and then decorate the autowired field with

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("mockMailSender")
private MailSender smtpkMailSender;
```