# ApplicationContext Exception in Test with @WebMvcTest

Tags: rest, unit-testing, spring-boot-test

I Have an Spring Boot Application (1.5.10.RELEASE) which contains a main (SpringBootApplication) like this:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@Configuration
@EntityScan(basePackages = { "db.modell", "db.modell.base" })
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "de.gui.test" })
public class SpringBootConsoleApplication {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SpringApplication.run(SpringBootConsoleApplication.class, args);
  }
}
```

and two REST controllers like the following:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/as")
public class AController {
  @Autowired
  private ARepository aRepository;

  @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public ResponseEntity<Collection<A>> getAs() {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(orgtFarbeRepository.findAll(), HttpStatus.OK);
  }

  @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public ResponseEntity<A> getA(@PathVariable long id) {
    A a = ARepository.findOne(id);

    if (party != null) {
      return new ResponseEntity<>(ARepository.findOne(id), HttpStatus.OK);
    } else {
      return new ResponseEntity<>(null, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
  }
}
```

Furthermore I have a single test like this:

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(AController.class)
public class AControllerTest {

  @Autowired
  private MockMvc mvc;

  @MockBean
  private ARepository ARepository;

  @Test
  public void firstTest() throws Exception {
    A a = new aFarbe();
    a.set....
    when(ARepository.findAll()).thenReturn(Collections.singleton(a));
    mvc.perform(
            get("/as")
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
    )
      .andExpect(status().isOk());
  }
}
```

The repositories look like this:

```java
public interface ARepository extends CrudRepository<A, Long>
{
    Collection<A> findAll();
}
public interface BRepository extends CrudRepository<B, Long>
{
  Collection<B> findAll();
}
```

A and B them self are JPA annotated classes. The whole application contains access to a database..

Furthermore I have a Service like this:

```java
@Service
public class XService {
  private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(XService.class);

  @Autowired
  private ARepository aRepository;

  @Autowired
  private BRepository bRepository;
...
}
```

The XService is not used via @Autowire or so (Just need to remove that):

So I try to run the AControllerTest I get the following error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext at
>   org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
>   .. .. at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:206)
>   Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'XService': Unsatisfied dependency
>   expressed through field 'BRepository'; nested exception is 
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type 'BRepository' available: expected at least 1
>   bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
>   .. .. at
>   org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:120)
>   at
>   org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
>   at
>   org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
>   ... 26 more Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type 'BRepository' available: expected at least 1
>   bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: 
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
>   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1493)
>   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1104)
>   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
>   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585)
>   ... 44 more

My assumption is that during the test more context is started than it should. The question is how can I prevent that? Which means only to start the context for the AControler and nothing more? I thought that based on the `@WebMvcTest(AController.class)` it should be limited already which looks like that it was not the case...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to exclude \*AutoConfiguration classes in Spring Boot JUnit tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26698071/how-to-exclude-autoconfiguration-classes-in-spring-boot-junit-tests)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The referenced answer does not really answered my question but a in the context a [hint](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42524526/296328) gave me the solution. This means in consequence to add the following to my test:

so I have to add `@OverrideAutoConfiguration(enabled=true)`:

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(OrgtFarbenController.class)
@OverrideAutoConfiguration(enabled=true)
public class AControllerTest {
...
}
```